# Expression Engine - import member data

Tags: expressionengine

I am finishing a site for a client and they want to import their customer database. Is there an effective way to import such data? I have used AJW Datagrab for importing data, but this is different.

Any suggestions?

I noticed that EE has an xml import template is there a handy way to convert a spreadsheet to an xml file that would fit that format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExpressionEngine 1.x used to come bundled with three native first-party Import Utilities:

- pMachine Pro Import Utility
- Movable Type Import Utility
- Member Import Utility

With the rewrite of ExpressionEngine 2.x, only the following made the conversion:

- Member Import Utility

You can access it within the Control Panel at: **CP Home > Tools > Utilities > Import Utilities**.

The first-party [Member Import Utility](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/tools/utilities/member_import/index.html) allows you to import members from other systems into ExpressionEngine, in the following two formats:

> - *Import from XML File* - Allows you to import members from an XML file
>     in ExpressionEngine's Member XML format.
> - *Convert Delimited Text to XML* - Allows you to create an
>     ExpressionEngine Member XML file from another application's delimited
>     text file.

If you're looking to import more than just Members into your ExpressionEngine database, [DataGrab](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab) by Andrew Weaver of Brand New Box in the UK is your best choice.

**DataGrab** allows you to import data from RSS/ATOM feeds, CSV files and XML files. Other datatypes can be added.

Among DataGrab's many uses are:

> - Importing initial content into ExpressionEngine from other CMS's (WordPress, Tumblr, etc.)
> - Aggregating data from your various websites from around the
>     internet, such as Twitter or Flickr (using RSS feeds or APIs)
> - Keeping product stock or price details synchronised with an external
>     system

You can also harness EE's powerful, built-in functionality (flexible templating, search, archives), DataGrab makes your data easily available as a channel entry.

The developer of DataGrab provides a walk thru on using [CSV imports with DataGrab](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/support/details/csv_imports_with_datagrab), perfect for use with Excel documents or a Google Docs Spreadsheets.

Surprisingly, the once-popular [Solspace Importer](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/importer/) still hasn't made the conversion to EE2.

Comment: Hi rjb, excellent. Thank once again for the detailed instructions. I have been using DataGrab on a number of projects and don't know how I would make it without it. I had not seen the member import utility but I believe that will fit the bill. The client has 300+ members to import and that would be one tedious job for someone to hand enter... Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but for the record Solspace Importer is now ee2.x compatible. The big advantage over DataGrab is Importer's ability to call with JSON.